# Using Decodable with injected properties

Tags: swift, parsing, cocoa, decodable

Is there any way to use `Decodable` with injected property?

```
final class Score: Decodable {
    let value: Int?
    let uniqueId: String

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder/*, uniqueId: String*/) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .value).flatMap { value = $0 }
        // self.uniqueId = uniqueId
        [... other properties parsing ...]
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
final class Exam {
    let identifier: Int
    let scores: [Score]
    
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        identifier = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .identifier)
        scores = try container.decode([Score].self, forKey: .scores)
        // I need to pass Exam's identifier to `score` on init, because it will generate Score's `uniqueId `
        [... other properties parsing ...]
    }
}
```

That would end with error with missing `uniqueId`, which I need to have after init but it's not in the JSON. Since it's identifier, making it optional and setting outside is not a proper way to handle it.

I'd love to inject it the way it's commented above, but how to do it?

Comment: And what is the source of uniqueId? If this had been a normal init, `init(uniqueId: String, value: Int)`, how would you have called it say if you wanted to create 10 objects from an array of 10 Int values?

Comment: If it comes from the parent object why do you need to set it or rather why do you need to redeclare it in the subclass if it exists in the superclass?

Comment: ? I don't think we're on the same page. I need unique identifier for the database, however the server doesn't return it, so I need to create it myself. I don't redeclare anything, however score is a property of a few other models, like `Exam` or `Report`. So I don't want to parse JSON score's value (and the other properties) in `Exam`, `Report` etc but only once inside `Score`. Thus the init you wrote doesn't help.

Comment: I haven't written any init, I am just trying to understand how I can help you with your question. Therefore I am trying to understand how uniqueId is created. So now it is not about inheritance anymore I guess.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm referring to the init from your first comment about "normal init". The question has nothing to do with inheritance - the class doesn't inherit from anything particular and nothing inherits from it. I need to pass the identifier of the object which has a property of this model and then I'll mix that identifier with something else. This way I'll have unique identifier which I can use in the database. I've updated the question, maybe now it's more clear?

Comment: Yes much clearer because now we have a source for the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extend the initialiser because it's being called indirectly and there is no API provided to extend it. Thus, there are several ways to bypass it:

1. BEST: Inject the value into Decoder's `userInfo` if possible.
2. Create separate class for Response and separate for model. Example below.
3. Use plain `JSONSerialization` instead of `Decodable`.
4. As @JoakimDanielson suggested, create random identifier inside default initialiser. The issue is that it's not reproducable, so in case you're saving it to the DB, you'll always override the data, since the ID with each parsing would be different.

Example for approach 2:

```
final class ScoreResponse: Decodable {
    let value: Int?

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .value).flatMap { value = $0 }
        [... other properties parsing ...]
    }
}

final class Score {
    let value: Int?
    let uniqueId: String

    convenience init(from response: ScoreResponse, uniqueId: String) {
        self.value = response.value // etc with other properties
        self.uniqueId = uniqueId
    }
}

final class Exam: Decodable {
    let identifier: String
    let scores: [Score] = []
    
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        identifier = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .identifier)
        try container.decodeIfPresent([ScoreResponse].self, forKey: .scores).forEach {
        scores.append({ Score(from: $0, uniqueId: identifier) })
    }
}
```